# Trying to extract date column and close price (SPY)

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to extract the following Dataframe from pandas

(Attributes - 1st Row Level, Symbol - 2nd Row Level, 0 - 3rd Row Level, 1 - 4th Row Level).

Is the following method correct: `pd.Dataframe.data['date','close']?`

```
Attributes        **date**      open                high                 low  \
Symbols                     AAPL       SPY      AAPL       SPY      AAPL   
0           **2017-01-03**  112.6732  217.9106  113.1889  218.6756  111.6613   
1           **2017-01-04**  112.7219  218.4722  113.3641  219.5664  112.6246   

Attributes               close              volume            
Symbols          **SPY**      AAPL       SPY      AAPL       SPY  
0           **216.7909**  113.0138  218.1043  28781865  91366522  
1           **218.4625**  112.8873  219.4018  21118116  78744433
```

Comment: What do you mean by `extract the following Dataframe from pandas`?

Comment: I meant extracting the date and close price(for SPY), which is in dataframe format. i.e. data['close']['SPY'] & data['date']